# Finding constants in a quadratic equation

Tags: functions, quadratics

I have the problem: 
Given that $g(x)$ is a quadratic function; that is in the form $g(x) = ax^2+bx+c$ for some constants $a,b,c$. Find the values of the constants $a,b,c$ given that $g(1)=6$, $g'(2)=24$, and $g''(3)=-4$.

I'm confused because it doesn't give me a the value for $g(0)$ so I don't know how i would start this problem.

Comment: $$g'(x)=g1(x)=2ax,$$  $$ g2(x)=g''(x)=2a$$

Comment: Yes that what I was trying to say.

Comment: you have three equations with three unknowns.

Answer (score 2):

You have three equations with three unknowns. Take the first derivative to get

$$g'(x)=2ax+b$$

and the second derivative

$$g''(x)=2a$$.

Now, we know that the second derivative at $x=3$ is -4. So,

$$g''(3)=2a=-4$$,

therefore, $a=-2$.

Now, we know that $g'(2)=24$, so

$$-4(2)+b=24$$
$$b=32.$$

Finally, we know that $g(1)=6$, so

$$-2(1)^2+32+c=6,$$

$$30+c=6$$

$$c=-24$$.

Answer (score 1):

You have $g(1) = 6$. That means that 
$$
a 1^2 + b 1 + c = 6
$$
i.e.,
$$
a + b + c = 6. (*)
$$
You have $g'(2) = 24$, which means that that
$$
2a\cdot 2 + b = 24
$$
i.e.
$$
4a + b= 24  (**)
$$
From the second derivative fact, you can derive a third equation:
$$
2a = -4 (***)
$$

Now, using the three starred equations, working from the bottom up, you can find $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: Small typo in $(**)$.

Comment: fixed; thanks much.